# Сумма квадратов числа

Tags: python, list

Начал изучать Python, столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Условия задачи следующие:

> По данному натуральному `n` вычислите сумму `1²+2²+3²+...+n²`.

У меня получился такой код, однако он не выводит верные значения. В чем может быть ошибка? Использовать нужно только `while`, без использования `for / range`:

```
n = int(input())
i = 0
sum = 0
while i < n:
    i = (i + 1)**2
    sum = i + n**2
print(sum)
```

Comment: С карандашом и бумагой пройдитесь по своему алгоритму, станет понятно.

Comment: Тоже изучаю питон, кмк, если нужен ответ одним (финальным) числом, то стоит добавить `if i < n: continue if i i == n перед print`, иначе в ответе будет выборка чисел

Answer (score 4):

```
n = int(input())
i = 1 # начинать с нуля не имеет смысла, т.к. 0^2 = 0
sum = 0

# наш цикл должен работать так же, как и for i in range(1, n+1). Поэтому условие именно такое, а на каждой итерации увеличиваем i на 1
while i <= n:
    sum += i**2 # добавляем квадрат этого числа к сумме 
    i += 1 
print(sum)
```

Comment: с единицы смысла не больше. можно сразу сумму приравнивать к 1.

Comment: Желательно бы оформить это всё в виде функции, однако это уже по желанию. Также возможно использование range().

Comment: И с первым, и со вторым соглашусь, но в условии было указано "без использования for / range"

Comment: @slippyk а если 0 элементов?

Answer (score 3):

> Использовать нужно только while

```
while True:
    print( n * (n + 1) * (2*n + 1) / 6 )
    break
```

Comment: Только `//` поставить вместо `/`

Comment: как жаль, что нельзя не использовать while

Answer (score 2):

```
x = int(input())
n = 0
y = 0
while n < x:
    y = y + (n + 1)**2
    n = n + 1
print(y)
```

Comment: `y += ...` есть такая конструкция для прибавления

Comment: Спасибо. Новичок. Еще пальцы не набил

Answer (score 2):

**Первая ошибка:**

В цикле

```
while i < n:
```

вы ожидаете, что значения переменной `i` будут постепенно `0`, `1`, `2`, ... `n-1`. Но непосредственно в первой команде цикла

```
    i = (i + 1)**2
```

переменную `i` изменяете.

Нужно использовать другую переменную, например

```
    square = (i + 1)**2
```

и значение переменной `i` поднять как последнюю команду цикла:

```
    i = i + 1     # или  i =+ 1
```

---

**Вторая и третья ошибка:**

```
    sum = i + n**2
```

- В предыдущей команде вы уже вычислили квадрат очередного числа и присвоили его переменной (теперь уже с именем) `square`. Значит, вместо `n**2` нужно использовать `square`.
- Вы хотите постепенно прибавлять к переменной `sum`, а не `i`. Значит, вместо `i` нужно использовать `sum`.

  ```
    sum = sum + square     # или  sum += square
  ```

---

**Ваша программа после применения правок:**

```
n = int(input())
i = 0
sum = 0
while i < n:
    square = (i + 1)**2
    sum = sum + square      # или  sum += square
    i = i + 1               # или    i += 1
print(sum)
```

Answer (score -1):

Без while можно.

```
a = int(input())
sum = 0
for i in range(1, a + 1):
    sum += i ** 2

print(sum)
```

Comment: Автор вопроса сказал "Использовать нужно только while, без использования for / range"